# Avoiding or alternative to use $_GET

Tags: php

I am currently using to process results via $_GET variable from querystring (URL) `http://example.com?id=c02df` and to update etc, as you know user can see what id being sent to the next page via url `(from above example id is c02df)` and can change the id from the URL himself. Kindly let me know is there any alternative way to exchange the ids between pages to process the functionality accordingly which user can't see or mess with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to use `$_SESSION`, if you don't want to allow users to tamper with the request.

If you provide more info on your code, I can provide more info on the solution.

EDIT: Here's a "workaround" for using both $_SESSION and $_GET (still without seeing your code at all):

You set `$_SESSION['allowed_gets'][] = 'c02df';`

Then, when the user is making the request, you check whether they are allowed to do that request:

`if (!in_array($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['allowed_gets'])){ die(); }`

Answer (score 1):

If you have content users shouldn't be able to see, you should have a login system.

If you just want unguessable URLs, avoid sequential IDs for the `$_GET` parameter. You could, for example, generate a salted MD5/SHA1 hash of the ID, store it in the database alongside the ID, and use that in the URL.